# Starting pop3 and imap services on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, postfix, email-server, imap, pop3

I'm running Mac OS X (Leopard) and I've just activated Postix, as well as installed UW imapd (a server capable of handling both IMAP and POP3 traffic).

The issue I'm having is that I don't know what file holds the commands to have Leopard start up the internet services (namely the ipop3d, and imapd services).

Previous versions of Mac OS X had a file: /etc/inetd.conf - but I understand that this file, as well as the /etc/xinetd.d directory has been removed from Leopard.

So, where do I add entries so the ipop3d, and imapd services can start on system bootup?

Thanks, ~Aki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual files and tools that you may be used to for starting/stopping/monitoring processes, such as xinetd, /etc/init.d, cron, and /etc/inittab, have been replaced on the Mac by launchd. It uses an XML file for configuring a service. Here are some resources to get you going:

Apple - [Getting Started with launchd](http://developer.apple.com/MacOsX/launchd.html)

Wikipedia - [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)

Mac Geekery - [All About launchd](http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/all_about_launchd_items_and_how_to_make_one_yourself)

(these came from a quick Google search)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OS X Leopard Server the mail services are controlled by the Server Admin utility.

Under the hood the services are managed by the `launchctl` command, check out the output of

```
sudo launchctl list
```

For example, you can start the `Postfix` service with the command

```
sudo launchctl start org.postfix.master
```

However you will have to configure `Postfix` manually.